# Full Calendar Need help - trying to do a weekly data

Tags: javascript, php, calendar, fullcalendar

[image]I'm having a hard time trying to do a weekly data,  the photo i uploaded on **left** side is the output im trying to get it  and on the **right** is my data structure

so my approach  explode > week_days  then foreach  get data for day names   which i'm unable to successfully form an ideal array for this one

is there any advice you guys could give me  or does this full calendar allows me to to this repetitively on weekly data manipulatively some functions that i dont know?

Comment: With reference to your comment "_so my approach explode > week_days then foreach get data for day names_": please can you add this as actual code into your post. Check SO Help Center to find out more about producing a 'Minimal Reproducible Example' >>> https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: "a hard time" and "unable to" isn't an error message or problem statement we can fix. We don't know what code you've written or exactly what errors or unexpected behaviour it produces. A _description_ of your code is not enough. If a simple description was enough to program the computer correctly, then we would not need programming languages! It's also unclear how your data structure could be used to create that output, there does not appear to be enough information in it. Please show the **actual code** and explain what output you get from it. Then we have some chance of helping you. Thanks.

Comment: P.S. What version of fullCalendar are you using? Are you aware that version 4 supports recurring events? See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/recurring-events. Depending on your overall requirements, this might simplify what you need to do.